# Entity Framework and Stored Procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using EF 4.3 to execute a stored procedure which just deletes some records and returns 0 when successfull else 1. When i execute the sp (using this.DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, id)) i'm getting -1 which is not what i'm expecting.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Basically the stored procedure is very simple:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Delete records here
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > @BeginTranCount
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN 1
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > @BeginTranCount
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
```

Also the sp doesn't return value with out variable.

Comment: please share your `storeProcedure`.

Answer (score 0):

We really need to see your code but here is the general idea:

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter() {  
    ParameterName = "@MyID",  
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output  
}; 

Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec @MyId = dbo.MyProc", id);
int retyrnedId = (int)id.Value;
```